# Adding arrow to bootstrap 3 menu?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I know i can add arrow to bootstrap 3 menu like going from down to up, is it possible to add menu thats goes from up to down, like this?

[image]

Here is code that i have for now:

```
 @media screen and (min-width:750px) {

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus:before {
        border-top: 20px solid #f00;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        left: 41%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8px 7px 0 7px;
    border-color: #1a161a transparent transparent transparent;
    z-index:1031
    }
```

Here is working bootply:

http://www.bootply.com/Yp4CciXyhb

The problem is here that this is on focus? If i click somewhere in the dropdown, arrow is gone?

Comment: sorry, i do not understand, when you want to show the arrow? when not?

Comment: When is on focus it is ok, try to click in dropddown, somewhere inside dropdown, not on link

Comment: the arrow gone due :focus selector. if dd lost focus, :focus selector does not match anymore, so the arrow gone. But what you want to achieve?

Comment: To stay when you when when focus is lost, only when close dropdown to gone